# Super Mario side-scrolling C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scroll

I'm trying to make the first level in Super Mario bros and I'm increasing the xstart which is the start of the image with constant rate as Mario moves right but the problem is every time Mario keeps moving faster than the image and his image width increases.

Here is the draw of the Bitmap

```
g.DrawImage(im,
new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height), //dest.
new Rectangle(xstart, 0, this.Width, this.Height), //src.
 GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

and I always increase the xstart with the movement of Mario and I can't see any problem in here..

```
player.x += 5;
xstart += 5;
```

Comment: What language are you using? c# or java? also, what is your question?

Comment: C# and my question is why the x of Mario increases faster than the xstart?

Comment: More code is need to provide an accurate assessment.

Comment: If the problem is with the movement, please provide the code you use to change the position

Comment: Are you sure you are clearing your screen? Could you be seeing his old spots rendered?

Comment: player.x is not proper C# syntax. It should be(if player is a field) Player.X I would suggest reading Microsoft's coding conventions for C# before continuing any further.

Comment: Yes I'm clearing the screen and the code of the changing position is written above and it's in the keydown event handler

Comment: ok thank you guys but I found the solution as if Mario exceeds for example this.width / 2, I should only increase the xstart not player.x

Comment: What is `im`, is it the player, or the background?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have to read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040(v=vs.110).aspx
You seem to mess with the parameters.

Maybe you are looking for something like :
`g.DrawImage(im,
 new Rectangle(xstart, 0, xstart + im.Width, im.Height), //dest area in win.
 new Rectangle(0, 0, im.Width, im.Height), //All the input img.
 GraphicsUnit.Pixel);`